# Not Call dependency in Mockito

Tags: unit-testing, mocking, mockito

I have below code, just putting one scenario here.

```
  class A{
 public JSONObject m1(type1,type2,type3){
    callmethod2(type3);
 }
 public Map callmethod2(type3){
    //some jobs
    return myMap;
 }
}
@Test
assertequals(JSONObjectTest,m1(type1,type2,type3))
```

In my test, I am creating a mock with dummy data and passing them to actual function **type1,type2,type3** Now there is callmethod2(type3) as a dependency so i do not want to execute that method. so in my test case i written

```
 when(mockA.callmethod2(any(type3.class))).thenReturn(mockMap);
```

But i can see my callmethod2 is getting execute, how can i solve this and set some expected result for that method in my test case, so it will not execute.

Comment: First of all, you really need to turn this into a question.  I assume you are asking "why do I see callmethod2 being called when I mocked it?".

Comment: Secondly, if you are testing class A, then you should almost never want to mock out any functionality within that class.  That is why it is called "unit testing".  Your unit is the class, and you access it through its exposed methods -- but you access the unit as it functions as a whole.

Answer (score 0):

Your code scenario at the time I am writing this is a little incomplete, but I will try to read between the lines.  I assume you are somewhere creating a mock instance of class A.  I am also assuming you are using that mocked instance to invoke the instance method "m1".

If either of these things are not true, then you will have problems.  If you do not create a mock instance, then the "when(...)" clause will not function properly, and in fact *while* you are invoking the "when" clause you will also actually be invoking the real (i.e., unmocked) instance of A.m1().  The same will be true if you properly mock A but then don't use the mocked instance in the "when" clause, or if you don't use the mocked version in your execute/assert statement(s).

But the bigger problem is that if you actually *ARE* properly creating and using a mock of A, then even the default mocked functionality of method "m1" becomes empty -- do nothing.  It would never get executed.  The only way to do what you seem to be proposing is to use what Mockito calls "partial mocking", using a Spy.  You instantiate a real instance of A, then wrap it in a Spy to make a "Spied"-instance of A.  Now the Spied instance of A inherits all of the default implementations of methods, and you can mock out specific methods if you like.  You then must use the spied instance in both yur "whe(...)" clauses as well as your execute/assert statements.

But even that endeavor is questionable.  You should try to test classes as a whole rather than mocking out partial behavior.  In general (practically a rule),you should either mock nor spy the class under test.  If you see a need to do so then there is probably a coherency problem with your class, and it is pointing to design issues or a misunderstanding of good testing practices.